# YouTube iFrame API hangs during buffering on iOS 8.* specifically in a chromeless home screen web app

Tags: ios, api, iframe, youtube, buffering

This problem has not been described clearly enough in other posts on stackoverflow and id like to start a new thread which specifically addresses a problem with the YouTube iFrame API when used in a web application that is added to the home screen on ios 8.* from safari.

In my web application, **playback works OK as expected when viewed in the mobile Safari web browser** on an iPhone running iOS 8.* (any version above 8).

**The specific problem i am trying to solve ONLY occurs when attempting to play a YouTube iframe embed after the web app is added to the home screen and launched from there.**

*I am going to exclude posting all of my code like the html markup or complete set of JS for example as it seems redundant; id like to get right to the point, but if anyone feels it is necessary, please respond and i will update this post.*

In the page head i include the necessary meta tag as follows:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

This enables the ability to "Add to Home Screen" from mobile Safari and have the web application load into a chromeless webview.

I also load the YouTube API in the page head as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

Once the web app is added to the home screen from Safari, launching it loads the web application into a chromeless webview as expected and embeds a YouTube video via the YouTube iframe API as per my JS further down in my code as follows:

```
var myPlayer = new YT.Player(MY_DIV_TARGET_ID, {
          videoId: MY_YT_VIDEO_ID,
          playerVars: {
      'autohide': 1,
          'autoplay': 0,
          'controls': 0,
          'ps': 'docs',
          'showinfo': 0,
          'color': 'white',
          'modestbranding': 1,
          'iv_load_policy': 3,
          'playsinline': 1,
          'rel': 0,
          'theme': 'dark'
          'enablejsapi': 1
            },
      events: {
        'onReady': onYouTubePlayerReady,
      }
    });
```

in my "onYouTubePlayerReady" function i am setting all the event listeners to track state and errors as per YouTube's instruction here: [YouTube iFrame API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

At that point, once a user physically taps the play button provided by YouTube in the embedded player *as required by Apple that a user must physically trigger playback by clicking/tapping a play button*, the video begins buffering and the event listener "onStateChange" fires with a result of 3 and/or YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING. All of this is expected behavior.

The UI updates with a spinner also as expected, but the player hangs at this point and **never** plays the video. **No errors** fire that i can see anywhere in the safari developer console that i can use to debug this problem. I am also not able to and/or do not know how to trace the percentage of the buffer either.

I have looked tirelessly for weeks online for a solution to no avail.

**ANY HELP EVER SO GREATLY APPRECIATED.**

Answer (score 0):

Also happens with Vimeo, DailyMotion and locally served HTML5 videos, for which these guidelines have been followed:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html

This problem has been introduced by iOS8 update, and still hasn't been addressed by Apple, which by now should be well aware of the issue (see various bug reports on SO).

I am testing with 8.2b5 and this issue is still not resolved.

My feeling is that they kind of want to force you into Apple eco-system and native apps to stream videos.

PS: same issues occur with `audio`